# How can I make this more efficient in Renderscript Android?

Tags: android, bitmap, renderscript

So to explain what I have; my application is a real time camera processing application. It  takes a bitmap of the current preview frame from a fragment, sends it to the main activity, and the main activity process the bitmap and displays it to another fragment that just holds an `imageView`.

So the cycle kinda goes like this:

```
Bitmap from Camera Live Preview Frame -> Process (Renderscript) -> Display output on ImageView.
```

The **process** part needs to happen as quick as possible.

This is my fragment:

```
public class CleanPreviewFragment extends Fragment implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {

    .......
    ....
    ...

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
        Bitmap origBmp = mTextureView.getBitmap();
        mCallback.onCleanPreviewBitmapUpdated(origBmp);
    }
}
```

My MainActivity:

```
public class MainPreviewActivity extends Activity
        implements CleanPreviewFragment.OnBitmapUpdatedListener {

       .......
       .....
       ....

        if(processedPreviewFragment != null) {
            processedPreviewFragment.setImageViewBitmap(
                    bProcessor.processBitmap(origBmp)
            );
        }
    }

}
```

My Processor Class:

```
    public class BProcessor {

         ......
         ....

    public Bitmap processBitmap(Bitmap bmp) {
        Bitmap modifiedBitmap;

        switch(function) {
            case 0:
                modifiedBitmap = simplefilters.inversePixels(bmp);
                break;
            case 5:
                modifiedBitmap = edgeDetection.apply(bmp);
                break;
            default:
                modifiedBitmap = bmp;
                break;
        }

        return modifiedBitmap;
    }
}
```

And for example my Edge Detection class and RenderScript.
Note: the Renderscript does not do `edge detection` it just averages pixels.

public class EdgeDetection {

```
private Allocation inAllocation;
private Allocation outAllocation;
private RenderScript mRS = null;
private ScriptC_edgedetect mScript = null;

public EdgeDetection(Context ctx) {
    mRS = RenderScript.create(ctx);
    mScript = new ScriptC_edgedetect(mRS, ctx.getResources(), R.raw.edgedetect);
}

public Bitmap apply(Bitmap origBmp) {
    int width = origBmp.getWidth();
    int height = origBmp.getHeight();

    //Bitmap bmpCopy = origBmp.copy(origBmp.getConfig(), true);

    inAllocation = Allocation.createFromBitmap(mRS, origBmp);
    outAllocation = Allocation.createFromBitmap(mRS, Bitmap.createBitmap(width,height,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888));

    mScript.set_width(width-1);
    mScript.set_height(height-1);
    mScript.set_inPixels(inAllocation);

    mScript.forEach_root(inAllocation,outAllocation);

    outAllocation.copyTo(origBmp);

        return origBmp;
    }
}
```

Renderscript:

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(com.apps.foo.bar)

rs_allocation inPixels;
int height;
int width;

uchar4 RS_KERNEL root(uchar4 in, uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {
  uchar4 out;
  float4 pixel = convert_float4(in).rgba;

  pixel.r = (pixel.r + pixel.g + pixel.b)/3;
  pixel.g = (pixel.r + pixel.g + pixel.b)/3;
  pixel.b = (pixel.r + pixel.g + pixel.b)/3;

  out = convert_uchar4(pixel);
  return out;
}
```

Now when I profile my app of course `onCleanPreviewBitmapUpdated` takes a lot of resources (gets called a lot of times etc etc).

Now in my `EdgeDetection` class, these line trouble me:

```
public Bitmap apply(Bitmap origBmp) {
    int width = origBmp.getWidth();
    int height = origBmp.getHeight();

    //Bitmap bmpCopy = origBmp.copy(origBmp.getConfig(), true);

    inAllocation = Allocation.createFromBitmap(mRS, origBmp);
    outAllocation = Allocation.createFromBitmap(mRS, Bitmap.createBitmap(width,height,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888));

    mScript.set_width(width-1);
    mScript.set_height(height-1);
    mScript.set_inPixels(inAllocation);

    mScript.forEach_root(inAllocation,outAllocation);

    outAllocation.copyTo(origBmp);

    return origBmp;
}
```

I used to have:

```
Bitmap bmpCopy = origBmp.copy(origBmp.getConfig(), true);
outAllocation = Allocation.createFromBitmap(mRS, bmpCopy));
```

and it still worked. I also had:

```
//Bitmap bmpCopy = origBmp.copy(origBmp.getConfig(), true);
outAllocation = Allocation.createFromBitmap(mRS, origBmp));
```

and it still worked (if someone could explain why the second part worked that would be great).

but I wanted to avoid operations as `origBmp.copy(origBmp.getConfig(), true);` as they can be slow right? So instead I am now using this:

```
outAllocation = Allocation.createFromBitmap(mRS, Bitmap.createBitmap(width,height,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888));
```

I am creating an empty Bitmap and passing to the Allocation. Is this correct?
Now it works but is it efficient? It seems that because of `Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888`. I had to change my Renderscript return value to a `uchar4` instead of `uchar3` to make it work.

Thanks

Comment: Think of Allocation objects as memory allocations for the RenderScript side. There is no reason to create a new bitmap object to "pass" to the Allocation.  The Allocation doesn't actually work that way. The parameters passed to the Allocation simply tell it how much memory to allocate. You're not copying the data back to the Java side until you call `outAllocation.copyTo()`

Comment: Also, why the conversion to a floating point in the script when there don't appear to be any floating point numbers involved?

Comment: You may want to try #pragma rs_fp_relaxed as you are defaulting to IEEE floating point math and can't take advantages of SIMD instructions. Alternatively look at other more efficient algorithms.

Comment: You may also wish to take a look at this tutorial [Camera Video Stream Processing
with RenderScript](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/c7/2b/CameraPipeline.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial link. @ChristopherSchneider, but I will need to pass my 'incoming' bitmap to the IN-allocation object right? That can't be empty. So the allocation object does hold data right? Otherwise where does the 'in' data come from in the renderscript?

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider I used the float4 conversion so I could access the r,b,g values I just removed it and it still works. Just another question, uchar4 holds numeric values of r,g,b,a (0-255)? Isn't it supposed to be a char var? Thanks

Comment: uchar4 is a vector of four unsigned chars. Just enough room for R, G, B and A. Also, you are correct about the IN allocation.

Comment: Just another question. an unsigned char can be used in mathematical operations? A char for R (Red) for example will be "138". How can that be used in a division? Shouldn't it be converted to a float?

Comment: Yes, you can use uchar in arithmetic. The thing you have to look out for is overflow, which is very likely to happen in this instance.

I think the better solution is to cast them to ints, average them, then cast back to uchar. You will have to use a bitmask, however. e.g.:

`uchar result = (uchar)(averagedResult & 0xFF)`

I believe that's the correct syntax, but I haven't done it in a few months.

Comment: No need to cast to int. It happens automatically when adding chars: [Integer conversion rules](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/INT02-C.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules)

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider I checked this, http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/guide/topics/renderscript/reference/rs_value_types.html#android_rs:uchar4 and it says that it returns "Four 8 bit unsigned integers" so casting to int will be pointless?